# In Ionic framework I am using iframe to autoplay youtube video but its not working in android

Tags: iframe, youtube-api, ionic-framework

I am new to the Ionic Framework.

I am using an iframe to embed YouTube video and also using `?autopaly=1` to autoplay the video, it's working in the browser but not in Android.

Comment: could you show me your code sample?

Answer (score 2):

Got embedded youtube videos to work in Ionic defining the URL in controllers.js with $scope then creating a filter in app.js.

Code for controllers.js

```
.controller('FooCtrl', function($scope,$stateParams) {
   $scope.videoSet = [
    [
      { url: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0?rel=0&amp;autoplay=1', t: '3:33'}
    ]
   ];
   $scope.videoId = $stateParams.videoId;
})
```

Code for app.js

```
.filter('trustAsResourceUrl', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(val);
    };
}])
```

Code for foo.html template

```
<ion-view view-title="Youtube Videos">
<ion-content ng-repeat="video in videoSet[videoId]">
    <ion-list>
        <div class="card">
            <ion-item>
                <iframe src="{{video.url | trustAsResourceUrl}}" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
            </ion-item>
        </div>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: Hi, i used your example code to make my youtube player video work and its all good except when i run it on the iPhone via Ionic View, I don't have any sound from the youtube movie. Perhaps you might know why?

Comment: Hi, great to hear that it worked ! I have found quite a few problems using html5 apis combined with Ionic View, whether it be on Android or iOs, so it might have something to do with that... You can find out more here maybe, or start a new issue : https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-view-issues/issues

Here's another link where you could find your solution : http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/embedding-youtube-videos-ios-platform/11896/5

Let me know if anything works for you, cheers